# We get paypal error 10423 with no clue what is wrong

Tags: paypal

We are a big webshop provider, and we have thousands of webshops in our system.

We have a case where we get an error in DoExpressCheckout with PaymentAction of Authorization here is the error

```
Ack: FAILURE

Build: 000000

Version: 117.0

Timestamp: 2017-04-06T08:54:36Z

CorrelationID: 4d6d16d1d30fa

ErrorCode: 10423

SeverityCode: ERROR

ShortMessage: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.

LongMessage: This transaction cannot be completed with PaymentAction of Authorization.
```

We have no clue what is wrong. Because it happens for specific paypal account of a specific customer.

We have two shops / one of a customer of us. Where we get the error. We made another shop in our system where we connected a paypal verified business account and then with another real personal account we bought an item from that shop and it all works. No errors.

We tried to the the same for this problematic customer and we get the error. We are sure that the code we use is the same in both cases and there is no difference in our handling. So the question is what could be wrong on the other paypal business account?

Could it be an SDK problem?

Comment: Can you check on your SDK if there is another parameter which pointing to Sale instead of Authorization?

Answer (score 2):

Did you even try to google it? I googled 'paypal 10423' and found:

Issue PayPal returned API error code 10423 - This transaction cannot be completed with PaymentAction of Authorization. Cause You set PaymentAction to "Sale" with SetExpressCheckout at the first API call.

Comment: Yes, I read that, but we set always PaymentAction to Authorize. We do not have any code that sets it to Sale and we have thousands of people per day that succeed, it is just this owner account that don't. So I am looking for a more sane explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this article may help you:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&expand=true&locale=en_US&id=FAQ1015

Apparently its because your setting the payment action to **sale** on a SetExpressCheckout then switching to **Authorization**. Paypal doesn't allow this and advises to set the PaymentAction to **Authorization** with the SetExpressCheckout then swap to **Sale** when setting the DoExpressCheckout call.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we post the request to SetExpressCheckout:

SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType req = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();

```
        .....

        PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
        paymentDetails.PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.AUTHORIZATION;            
        paymentDetails.ShipToAddress = ....
        req.PaymentDetails.Add(paymentDetails);
```

So we are 100% sure we use Authorize, and we do the same for DoCheckout, so it seems like PayPal is thinking we did Sale as PaymentAction why is that?